# How Does Email Authentication on Mobile Works?

Tags: javascript, flutter, express, authentication

I'm currently building an app version of my web app, and I want to have some clarity on some things.

Let's say that I have built an authentication flow for my web-app. I asked for email in the web, user clicked submit after filling the form, we sent them a link to their email address, and after clicking the link in the email, they are logged in.

I'm trying to do the same on mobile-app, how does it work? For example, after the user clicked the link in their email, how do they get automatically logged in to their app?

Comment: OAuth + json web token? Mobile apps usually work with rest apis instead of cookie session

Comment: I'm guessing the link takes them to a web page which opens the app.